# C: Defined behaviour returning wrong result

Tags: c, user-defined-functions

So I have an exam tomorrow and I encountered this on my questions.

```
#define mul(x,y) (x * y)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    int z = 0;
    z = mul(x+1, y+1);
    printf("4 * 5 = %d \n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is, why is this outputting 8 instead of 20.
Because when I replace `z= mul(x+1,y+1)` with `z= mul((x+1),(y+1))` I get the correct answer of 20

Comment: it expands to `(x + 1 * y + 1)`, which is probably not what you'd expect, you need some more brackets.

Comment: Read your last sentence carefully again. See the output of the preprocessor and then think about what you learned at your elementary school math class.

Comment: ...  One good reason for not using macros

Comment: @EdHeal: Oh, macros do have their usage. Just not where a(n `inline`) function will do as well.

Comment: @Olaf - I agree they sometimes do. But better to avoid them though IMHO

Comment: @EdHeal: I normally keep it with writing understandable/readable code which can also be debugged properly (unless optimisations are unavoidable). If a macro suits better for this goal, I'm fine. If both are similarily suited, the function wins. Until now, no user of my code (that includes myself) complained:-) But I'm quite sure that's what you mean, too.

Comment: @Olaf - Would they dare complain ;-)

Comment: @EdHeal: Not often. But my customers and co-workers well know I take a complain serious if there are good arguments. Despite what one might think, I'm very willing to acept if I'm **proved** wrong. (notice the emphasis, though:-)

Comment: @Olaf - The comment was tongue in cheek :-)

Comment: @EdHeal: I got that already ;-P

Answer (score 3):

Macro `#define mul(x,y) (x * y)` actually tells the pre-compiler that if it finds string **mul(*any pattern X*, *any pattern Y*)**, it should replace it with **(*any pattern X* * *any pattern Y*)**.

So what do you have in your example?

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int z = 0;
z = mul(x+1, y+1);
```

After `mul` is replaced, you get

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int z = 0;
z = x+1*y+1;
```

==> z = 3 + 1*4 + 1 = 8

The best practice is to surround each macro parameter by brackets. In your example (to achieve the desired result) it should be:

```
#define mul(x,y) ((x) * (y))
```